# How to deserialize old and new records in a topic Kafka that its schema registry changes over time?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have an issue to read from a topic that its schema registry changes with upgrades tell now it has the fourth version of Avro file. I think that the first records in that topic have the structure of the first version of the Avro structure and the last records in the topic have the newest version.

My question how can I deserialize the old and the new records from this topic?

Please note that I have exported the two schemas with theirs ids from schema registry.

The exception message is shown when I'm using the old avro schema that has the id 10.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition topicvalues_out_v1-1 at offset 334224. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro unknown schema for id 10
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot get schema from schema registry!
```

and when I'm using the newer avro schema that has the id of 25 it throws the same exception

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition topicvalues_out_v1-1 at offset 334224. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retrieving Avro unknown schema for id 25
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot get schema from schema registry!
```

Comment: What "issues" are you running into? By default, the registry doesn't let you make incompatible schema changes, so any newer schema is able to deserialize records of older ones

Comment: I'm facing issues with the Ids of these schemas, it says that they do not exist on the schema registry even if I explored it from there. I'll add the exception message.

Comment: I feel like I've seen this error in the github issues sometimes... What version of the registry are you using? Are you able to get the server logs when your client (what version of this too?) tries to access those ids? Is it only your code throwing the exceptions, or does Avro console consumer fail too? And can you share the full stacktrace that includes the deserializer methods?